# How to use wget in case like json?

Tags: server, wget, downloaders

Suppose we have json like this:

```
[{
    "title": "How to download File From Node Js",
    "extension": "mp4",
    "url" : "http://zzz.com/asd/what.mp4",
    "folder__relative_path": "tutorial/node"
}, {
    "title": "How to play Guitar",
    "extension": "mp4",
    "url" : "http://asdz.com/asd/dsa.mp4",
    "folder__relative_path": "another_folder/hello/tutorial/Guitar"
}
....
more
more
....
]
```

So basically We have a json file with information about download url , path and file name with extension. We just want to download from the above link .

How do I download rename with title with extension and save to the directory we specified;

We know we can use wget like this

```
wget www.zzz.com/1.mp4 -O /var/cache/foobar/google.mp4
```

but isn't it hard to fetch and save from json ??

Is there anyway to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Python to [parse the JSON](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) and [run `wget`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html):

```py
#! /usr/bin/python3
import json, sys, subprocess

for k in json.load(sys.stdin):
    cmd = ["echo", "wget", k["url"], "-O", '{:s}/{:s}.{:s}'.format(k["folder__relative_path"], k["title"], k["extension"])]
    subprocess.run(cmd)
```

With the sample input:

```
$ python3 f.py < foo.txt
wget http://zzz.com/asd/what.mp4 -O tutorial/node/How to download File From Node Js.mp4
wget http://asdz.com/asd/dsa.mp4 -O another_folder/hello/tutorial/Guitar/How to play Guitar.mp4
```

Remove `"echo",` to actually execute the `wget` commands after you verify the output.

Comment: Do it require python3.5?

Comment: @MeNoobSir because of `subprocess.run()`? No, you can replace that with `subprocess.call()` instead.